# How can I read this file with space?

Tags: c, readfile

```
1 0 Robin Fernandao
2 0 Christiano Gomez
3 1 Lionel Maradona
```

I have a file that has content like above and I'm trying to read in while loop `fscanf(filename,"%d %d %s",array[i],array2[i],array3[i]);`  Everything ok without player name. It gives me name without last name.How can I fix it? is there any way to read like this file

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
fscanf(filename,"%d %d %[^\n]",array[i],array2[i],array3[i]);
```

Comment: for(i = 0; fscanf(fp,"%d %d %[^\n]%*c",&array1[i],&array2[i]),array3[i] != -1; i++) {  }  I was able to but when I tried to print they it's give wrong output because of array3

Comment: @Yasin; I didn't get you.

Comment: @Yasin : Different problem - ask a new question; with code.

Comment: @Yasin Don't compare to `!= -1` instead `== 3`